# Индексирование сайта

Tags: seo

Как проидексировать сайт в поисковых системах, чтобы при наборе спецслов выходила ссылка на сайт?

Answer (score 5):

**Поисковая оптимизация** - *процесс работы над сайтом, его внутренними факторами, влияющими на ранжирование в поисковых системах – структурой, контентом, кодом HTML, его внешними факторами ранжирования – ссылками на сайт с целью увеличения релевантности ресурса определенным, зараннее известным ключевым словам, увеличения популярности сайта для поисковых машин и, соответственно, увеличения позиций в поисковых результатах для привлечения большего количества посетителей на сайт. Профессионалы SEO должны разбираться в алгоритмах работы различных поисковых систем, как они индексируют контент, алгоритмах поиска и ранжирования сайтов, а также профессионалы должны понимать то, как пользователь ищет нужный материал, его психологические особенности при работе с сетью Интернет.*

После создания сайта, как уже известно, его используют люди и поисковые роботы и, в зависимости от качества оптимизации, и те и другие формируют свое отношение к нему с помощью каких-то критериев.

Например, **для пользователей** основными критериями являются:

- Полезность контента на сайте для посетителя;
- Соответствие контента тому, что искал посетитель;
- Удобство использования ресурса,
- Быстрая загрузка,
- Минимум отвлекающих факторов;
- .....

Для **поисковых роботов** основные критерии полезного сайта это:

- Минимум технических ошибок на сайте,
- Удобство индексации;
- Соответствие заголовка контенту;
- Ссылочная популярность ресурса;
- .....

## C чего же начать продвижение?

### 1. Определение целей

- просто наличие сайта в поисковике;
- высокие позиции в поисковиках по каким-то интересным на ваш взгляд запросам;
- обгон конкурентов в позициях по некоторым запросам;
- увеличение посещаемости ресурса (траффика);
- поиск целевой аудитории и постоянных заинтересованных клиентов;
- увеличение коэффициента конверсии и, соответственно, заработка на рекламе или партнерской программе;
- другие цели…

В зависимости от выбранной цели будет формироваться свой план продвижения и свои методы формирования отчетов и анализа результатов раскрутки. Допустим, что мы просто хотим, чтобы наш сайт находился в поиске, причем выше конкурентов, если таковые имеются.

### 2. Формирование ядра запросов и их группировка

*Некоторые называют этот шаг составлением сематнического ядра. Заключается он в следующем: необходимо найти ту группу запросов, которая наиболее максимально подходит к вашему сайту. На данном этапе следует прекрасно понимать свою будущую аудиторию, её интересы, возраст, пол, поставить себя на место пользователя и представить, какие запросы были бы наиболее релевантны для вашего сайта.*

Например, у вас сайт посвящен продаже букетов цветов, значит, вероятнее всего, главный запрос будут иметь вид “доставка букетов”. Смотрим [статистику ключевых слов](http://wordstat.yandex.ru/?cmd=words&geo=&page=1&text=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2&text_geo=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5) по этому запросу в Яндексе (также там можно указать регион поиска) и видим (в правой колонке), что наряду с нашим запросом пользователи также ищут: букеты Москва, заказать цветы, купить цветы, бизнес букет, заказ букетов и т.д. Выберите основные из этих высокочастотных запросов.

Когда вы определитесь с ВЧ, переходите к определению СЧ и НЧ запросов, анализируя левую колонку в статистике Яндекса. Также можно использовать статистику рамблера для более детального анализа.

Группировать запросы следует по их принадлежности к определенному ВЧ, например, фразы из одной группы:

- доставка букетов
- доставка букетов цветов
- доставка букетов по москве
- букеты на заказ с доставкой
- цветы доставка купить букет …

### 3. Анализ конкуренции по каждому из запросов

Вводите в поиск сперва ваши высокочастотные запросы и смотрите, какие из сайтов стоят на первых местах, есть ли контекстная реклама по этому запросу?

### 4. Аудит сайта

После того, как мы познакомились с нашим конкурентом, нам необходимо узнать подробно свой сайт и для этого провести его аудит. Аудит сайта это довольно широкая задача и требует времени и внимания, этот этап должен проводиться человеком, уже имеющим определенные знания в SEO, а также опыт подобных анализов. В процессе анализа своего сайта необходимо выявить все его достоинства и недостатки, частично внутренний аудит сайта можно выполнять с помощью [программы xenu](http://devaka.ru/articles/xenu-link-sleuth).

Также на этом этапе следует проанализировать как в настоящее время относятся поисковые системы к этому сайту (индексируют, нет ли фильтров, кто раньше ссылался на наш сайт и т.д.).

Заметьте, что до этого момента мы не предпринимали никаких действий с сайтом, несмотря на то, что была проделана огромная работа. Была проделана очень важная подготовительная часть, без которой не возможно ни одно продвижение. Не всегда эту работу понимают заказчики, так как ничего визуально не поменялось, однако лишь с этим багажом знаний можно двигаться дальше.

### 5. Внутренняя оптимизация

Следующий этап в нашем плане раскрутки сайта это внутренняя его оптимизация. Данный этап подготавливает сайт к продвижению, делает его видимым в поисковых системах и заставляет их полюбить данный ресурс, как в общем и пользователей, зашедших на него. Внутренняя оптимизация состоит из нескольких частей, выделим три главные из них.

#### 5.1. Выбор страниц под каждую группу ключевых слов

По всем запросам двигать одну главную страницу невозможно и глупо, поэтому следует выбрать те страницы (если их нет, то добавить), которые вы будете оптимизировать под ту или иную ключевую фразу из вашего ядра запросов.

Обычно главная страница оптимизируется под высокочастотные запросы (высококонкурентные), страницы второго уровня (напр., категории) под среднечастотные и остальные страницы со статьями или продуктами магазина с описанием должны оптимизироваться под низкочастотные запросы. Это делается потому, что на практически всех движках, используемых для создания сайтов, вес перераспределяется так, что большая его часть приходится на главную страницу, а меньшая на вложенные страницы, находящиеся в 2-3 (и более) кликах от главной.

#### 5.2. Оптимизация контента

На данном шаге необходимо оптимизировать контент на выбранных страницах, чтобы он был максимально релевантен тем ключевым словам, под которые эти страницы будут раскручиваться. В оптимизацию контента входит (основные пункты):

1. Оптимизация тайтлов страниц.
2. Редактирование самого текста.
3. Редактирование заголовков текста, alt атрибутов изображений и т.д.
4. Улучшение дизайна и других характеристик качества целевых страниц. Создание условий для мотивации посетителя к действиям (покупке товара, подписке на обновления, сохранению ссылки в закладках и т.д.).

#### 5.3. Оптимизация внутренней перелинковки в соответствии с ядром запросов

Естественно, что наиболее важные страницы должны иметь максимум веса. Представьте, что у вас есть несколько магазинов по продаже букетов, один расположен в центре города, другой на его окраине. Центральный магазин будет пользоваться большим спросом, поэтому вам необходимо будет туда поставлять товар намного чаще, чем во второй. Также и со страницами при SEO оптимизации. Те страницы, которые будут давать максимальную отдачу, нужно прокачать максимальным весом.

Это называется перелинковкой. Чем лучше изначально вы перелинкуете страницы своего сайта, тем меньше этому придется уделять внимания в будущем.

### 6. Добавление сайта в поисковики и другие поисковые ресурсы

После того, как вы оптимизировали сайт внутренне, необходимо дать знать о нем другим людям. Для этого, прежде всего, [зарегистрируйте его в поисковых системах](http://devaka.ru/articles/addurl). Попробуйте подать заявки на регистрацию в [DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/World/Russian/) и [Яндекс.Каталоге](http://yaca.yandex.ru/).

Можно обойтись и без этого пункта, поисковики склонны сами находить интересные сайты в сети, но можно и подстраховаться, если вы сомневаетесь в качестве своего сайта.

### 7. Внешняя оптимизация

Внешняя оптимизация это также неотъемлемая часть продвижения, так как на данный момент поисковики оперируют с внешними ссылками для определения рейтинга и популярности сайта. Если всю предыдущую работу вы можете выполнить единожды, то внешнюю оптимизацию необходимо производить постоянно, чтобы поддерживать нужные позиции в поиске.

В зависимости от подхода к ссылкостроению (синоним внешней оптимизации) внешние ссылки размещаются на определенных ресурсах на свободной или платной основе. Это могут быть каталоги сайтов (что категорически не рекомендуется для молодых неокрепших ресурсов), сайты схожей тематики и региона (в последнее время актуально), каталоги статей и пресс-релизов и множество других сайтов. Методов ссылкостроения сотни, не ограничивайтесь лишь двумя-тремя, ищите их на форумах и блогах, а также самостоятельно разведывайте лазейки, где можно получить хорошие ссылки пусть даже с большими временными затратами.

Подумайте, где может находиться ваша основная аудитория и найдите эти места в сети. Это могут быть всевозможные форумы, группы в социальных сетях и любые другие социальные ресурсы. Очень полезно разместить информацию о вашем сайте на этих ресурсах, чтобы люди и поисковые системы узнали о вас и начали индексировать.

В данном случае не стоит перегибать палку, как это свойственно многим “оптимизаторам”, когда они начинают спамить по форумам своими анонсами, приглашать всех посетить сайт вконтакте и т.д. Помните, что одна хорошая ссылка “для людей” даст больше доверия сайту, чем 100 спамных.

Если у вас коммерческий сайт, тогда необходимо рассмотреть также пункты покупки ссылок, как основного момента современной внешней оптимизации сайта различными SEO компаниями. Подробней об этом будут следующие посты, а пока лишь перечислим основные этапы внешней оптимизации (в том числе с помощью коммерческих ссылок), каждый из которых требует определенного времени и усилий.

**Этапы работ могут быть такими:**

- Определение бюджета на ссылки
- Составление текстов ссылок
- Размещение ссылок на внешних ресурсах
- Контроль размещенных ссылок
- Анализ эффективности размещения
- Корректировка стратегии
- Подготовка отчета
- Оптимизация и корректировка ссылочного бюджета

> Целью данной статьи не было рассказать о том, как продвигать сайт. Это невозможно объяснить даже в отдельной книге, так как, во-первых, количество подходов к оптимизации и раскрутке сайта очень велико и, во-вторых, Интернет как живой организм — постоянно развивается и совершенствуется: то, что работало вчера уже неэффективно сегодня, нужно постоянно быть, как говориться, в струе, если заниматься SEO.
>
> Целью этой статьи было рассказать коротко новичкам о плане, которому можно следовать на начальном этапе. Не стоит забывать о своих целях, о релевантных вашему сайту запросах, об аудите своего сайта и сайтов-конкурентов. Перед тем, как проводить внешнюю оптимизацию сайта, выставлять его на публику, размещая ссылки на различных ресурсах, в том числе и коммерческие ссылки, необходимо провести внутреннюю оптимизацию сайта, чтобы уменьшить показатель отказов и большинство посетителей, также как и поисковых ботов, заставить полюбить вас и невольно помогать делать вас популярней.

**Главное, это понимание основных этапов и принципов работ по продвижению сайта, а именно:**

#### 1. Принципы работы поисковых систем

- Основы устройства поисковых систем.
- Типы пользовательских запросов.
- Индексация поисковыми системами.
- Персонализация выдачи.
- Плюсы и минусы разных способов продвижения сайта.
- Факторы ранжирования сайтов.
- Алгоритмы поисковых систем.

#### 2. Постановка и отслеживание целей

- Определение целей и задач сайта.
- SEO-планирование, прогнозирование и расчет SEO-бюджета.
- Риски, проблемы и ожидаемые результаты от SEO-продвижения.
- Яндекс.Метрика, Яндекс.Вебмастер,
- Google Analytics, Google Webmaster.

#### 3. Работа с семантическим ядром

- Подбор семантического ядра.
- Ручной способ подбора ключевых запросов для вашего сайта, обзор программ и сервисов для автоматизации подбора ключевых слов для вашего сайта.
- Очистка ключевых запросов от дублей, стоп-слов, опечаток, группировка ключевых слов в зависимости от целей вашего бизнеса.
- Семантическое ядро для молодых сайтов и сайтов в возрасте.

#### 4. Внутренняя и внешняя оптимизация сайта

- Методы внутренней оптимизации.
- Верстка текста с методами SEO-оптимизации: работа с тегом title и мета-данными, перелинковка и распределение веса внутри сайта, правильное написание файлов robots.txt, .htaccess, 301-редиректы.
- Специфика подбора запросов для продвижения главной страницы.
- Анализ и измерение показателей качества внутренней оптимизации.
- Анализ ссылочных агрегаторов, доноров, ссылочной массы.

#### 5. Поисковый маркетинг

- Оптимизация поведенческих факторов.
- Фильтры поисковых систем.
- Антиспам.
- Способы защиты от фильтров поисковых систем.
- Выбор подрядчика по SEO-оптимизации.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно для значения вашего слова "спецслов", вы имели ввиду ключевые слова.

- Исследуйте ключевые слова вашего веб-сайта в планировщике ключевых слов **AdWords Google** или же **[SemRush](https://www.semrush.com/)** и определите наиболее часто задаваемые слова по теме вашего сайта.
- Создайте информативные **заголовки** для каждой страницы вашего сайта с использованием выявленных ключевых слов.
- Создайте **оригинальное описание** для каждой страницы вашего сайта с использованием выявленных ключевых слов - **[справка Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=ru)** + **[Справка Гугл Вебмастер](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/ru/stati/kak-ulucsit-opisanie-sajta-v-rezultatah-poiska-pri-pomosi-meta-tega-description)**.
- Примените формат **[PageMap Google](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1628213?hl=ru)** для каждой страницы вашего сайта с использованием выявленных ключевых слов.
- Примените **разметку структурированными данными** - [инфо Гугл](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data).
- Примените разметку **[OpenGraph Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/)** с использованием выявленных ключевых слов - для этого используйте **хэштэги** - [инфо Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/587836257914341).
- Примените файлы **[OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1)** и/или **[Atom](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1633)** для каждой страницы вашего сайта с использованием выявленных ключевых слов.